# Concat Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CONCAT(me.nativeName,tp.nativeName) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(e_node,e_n_t)
                                                          FROM m_tp_info
                                                          WHERE m_id = mid)
```

Is there any way to optimize this concat?

Comment: Yes, compare separate columns instead of the concated values. (Perhaps do a NOT EXISTS, to be null-safe.)

Comment: @jarlh That would assume the component parts are equal, e.g. `CONCAT('ABC', 'DEF') = CONCAT('AB', 'CDEF')`, however, the two component parts are not equal. Niranjan, can you confirm whether this could happen?

Comment: @GarethD, of course, depending on what the OP wants. (I guess the opposite bug is more common, treating ABC and DEF unintentionally the same as AB and CDEF.)

Answer (score 1):

With most DBMS I would approach this in the way that semantically makes sense:

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    ...
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    m_tp_info AS i
            WHERE   i.mid = me.m_id
            AND     CONCAT(i.e_node, i.e_n_t) = CONCAT(me.nativeName,tp.nativeName)
        )
```

But MySQL will usually optimise [`LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` better than `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/), so you might try:

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    ...
        LEFT JOIN m_tp_info AS i
            ON i.mid = me.m_id
            AND CONCAT(i.e_node, i.e_n_t) = CONCAT(me.nativeName,tp.nativeName)
WHERE   i.mid IS NULL;
```

Of course, if you are just using `CONCAT` becuase you want to compare two columns and `NOT IN` does not allow this, then you could just join on the two columns:

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    ...
        LEFT JOIN m_tp_info AS i
            ON i.mid = me.m_id
            AND i.e_node = me.nativeName
            AND i.e_n_t = tp.nativeName
WHERE   i.mid IS NULL;
```

Or

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    ...
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    m_tp_info AS i
            WHERE   i.mid = me.m_id
            AND     i.e_node = me.nativeName
            AND     i.e_n_t = tp.nativeName
        );
```